# ¿Cómo se llama la manecilla del reloj que señala las horas?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, significado, sustantivos

En un reloj analógico, la manecilla que señala los segundos es el [segundero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XTM6GRg). La de los minutos es el [minutero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PL5bOLS). Pero ¿y la de las horas?

Comment: La manecilla pequeña.  Así siempre lo he oído nombrar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **[horario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ke9JU87)**
>
> Del lat. *horarius*.
>
> 3. m. Manecilla de reloj que señala las horas, y es siempre algo más corta que el minutero.

Comment: Curioso, no tenía ni idea y nunca me lo había preguntado. Lo malo es que horario se usa más con sus otras acepciones, si alguien me dijera que se le ha roto el horario del reloj me quedaría muy extrañado y no entendería la frase (antes de leer esta respuesta, claro).

Comment: @blonfu el caso es que me lo preguntó un compañero del trabajo, se lo busqué porque yo tampoco tenía ni idea, y pensé que podría ser un dato curioso para compartir aquí.

Comment: En algunos paises de América es *horero* como cabría esperar si seguimos la lógica de *minuter*o y *segundero*: http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=horero

Comment: ¡Qué buena! Lo había pensado pero nunca se me pasó por la cabeza que vendría siendo esa la palabra.